# Routing scroll events to ScrolledPanel in wxPython without routing focus

Tags: python, scroll, focus, wxpython

So I've got a frame containing multiple wx.Panels containing both a wx.TextCtrl and a wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel. I want to route any mouse scroll events to the ScrolledPanel when the mouse is over the wx.Panel (so either the TextCtrl or the panel, without either of them necessarily having focus) - *without* routing focus away from whatever control previously had it.

For example, the solution I had found previously was to make any mouse movement over the ScrolledPanel give it focus - but this routed focus away from the TextCtrl.

I've tried binding EVT_MOUSEWHEEL on the wx.Panel, but that doesn't appear to do anything when I grab either event.GetWheelDelta() or event.GetWheelRotation()

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On each wx.Panel on that ScrolledPanel you will have to bind an event to set the focus to the ScrolledPanel when there is mouse motion over it.

```
class ListItem(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ListItem, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

        #Add all your other objects to this panel as normal

    def OnMouseMotion(self, event):
        panel = event.GetEventObject().GetParent()        
        panel.SetFocus()
```

You can also do it in-line if you're not creating a class for each listed panel on your scrolled panel:

Answer (score 0):

Does unbinding the scrollwindows focus events work?

```
    self.scrollwin.Unbind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS)
    self.scrollwin.Unbind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS)
```